# Getting .startsWith() is not a function in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to search items through a search bar.The original items are in prod.but I keep getting startsWith() not a function and sometime .toLowerCase() is not a function

```
const [prod, setprod] = React.useState([]);
const [getFiltered, setFiltered] = React.useState([]);
const [getSearch,setSearch]=React.useState("");


const SearchItem=(text)=>{
  if(text!=""){
    const searched=prod.filter((item)=>{
      const datachange=item.toLowerCase();
      const textchange= text.toLowerCase();
      return datachange.startsWith(textchange);
    });
    setFiltered(searched);
    setSearch(text)
  }
  else{
    setFiltered(prod);
    setSearch(text);
  }}
```

Comment: We'll need to see how you're filling `prod` and where you're calling `SearchItem`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @lucasvw that more information would be helpful here.

However, your conditional is only validating that `text!=""`, but if text is something else, like a number, function, or (more likely) `undefined` or `null`, this will throw.

I'd recommend changing to something like this:

```js
if (typeof text === "string" && text != "") {
# the rest of your code
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, it's actually `item` that's throwing.

Same idea, but try this instead:

```js
    const searched=prod.filter((item)=>{
      if (typeof item !== "string") {
        return false;
      }
      const datachange=item.toLowerCase();
      const textchange= text.toLowerCase();
      return datachange.startsWith(textchange);
    });
```